# Autofocus mode vuforia slow

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have a question for the FOCUS MODE of Vuforia, CONTINUOUSAUTO:

It works, but is too much slow.. and not much accurate,
There is a way to make it more fast? call the one shot autofocus more fast in time? or more accurate?

Vuforia latest version

Unity  5.4.0

Testing on: Samsung S6

My C# script in WebcamBehaviour of the ARCamera:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 using UnityEngine;

 namespace Vuforia
{
/// <summary>
/// This MonoBehaviour manages the usage of a webcam for Play Mode in Windows or Mac.
/// </summary>
public class WebCamBehaviour : WebCamAbstractBehaviour
{
    void Start(){

        VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.RegisterVuforiaStartedCallback (OnVuforiaStarted);
        VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.RegisterOnPauseCallback (OnPaused);
        }

    private void OnVuforiaStarted()
    {
        CameraDevice.Instance.SetFocusMode (CameraDevice.FocusMode.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUSAUTO);
    }
    private void OnPaused (bool paused){
        if (!paused) //resumed
        {
            //Set again autofocus mode when app is resumed
            CameraDevice.Instance.SetFocusMode (
                CameraDevice.FocusMode.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUSAUTO);
        }
    }
}
}
```

It Works, but i need a better accuracy..
Have you any ideas?

Thanks,

Marcello

Answer (score 1):

Set the focus mode of the camera before vuforia starts. Also test your app performance and improve iT: load only what is needed, use less FPS, a smaller videocapture, and use minimal rendering resources.